# Where to store files in Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Inside the project folder there is a "project's name" folder, Release and Debug folder. I'm right now working in debug mode and my files keep getting updated everytime i run it, and i copy it into the other 2 folders everytime to avoid confusion. Is this the right way to do it or is it enough if the files are in the main folder ?

Comment: What files get updated? You shouldn't need to be copying files out of the Debug and Release folders.

Comment: its a heuristic process where values are added or updated to match different inputs during testing, so i want to make sure these updated files are safe and are the ones that are accessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have files in the project that need to be copied to the current output folder on build then select the appropriate options in the file's properties: select the file in solution explorer and then set the properties of that file:

- Build Action: None
- Copy to output directory: Copy Always, or Copy If Newer.

Thus VS will put the files in the right place on build. You do not need to maintain multiple copies.

Answer (score -1):

If your program needs access to text files,  images, etc. which are separated from the program's code, you can put these both into the debug or into the release folder.
Beware that if you modify these files into the debug folder, you must update the files into the release, and vice-versa. This is valid if you use to switch between the debug mode and the release mode. If you use only the debug mode as I do while I'm developing, you could put all the files in the debug folder only, and copy these files into the release folder only when you will end the development.

Comment: i'm running the project in debug mode, but its not accessing the files from that folder, its accessing the files from that prorgram name folder

Comment: -1: Poor idea. Duplicating files is the wrong approach. VS can handle copying files to the output itself with you maintaining just a single copy.

Comment: It would be better to have the files in one place and make post-build event which will copy required files either to Debug or Release (or win32/Debug, or x64/Debug, or...) after build and before running the application.

Comment: @Richard: I found situation in which, without having some images into the Debug folder, VS doesn't found them itself. So...